# Monitoring Redis and mysql server for memory and cpu usage

Tags: mysql, monitoring, memory-usage, cpu-usage, redis

I want to compare the memory and cpu usage of the the redis-server and the mysql-server. I have used a profiler to get the client data but I would also like to know what is going on on the servers when I execute queries.

Do you know a tool that I could use.

I am running them locally on mac os x10.6.8

Answer (score 2):

You can run a query against your information_schema table to get my mysql stats on current usage by MEMORY tables, if you use them:

`select sum(data_length+index_length) as memory from information_schema.tables where engine='memory';`

Also if you use INNODB, you can run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` granted you have the PROCESS privelage

Answer (score 0):

There's an easy way for redis.

There's a comand for the command line client (redis-cli) called INFO. which shows (among others) a variable called "used_memory".

see http://redis.io/commands/info

Comment: Yes I know that :) and I use it, but I would like to see if my processes cause extra load on the servers.